# Friend function from another namespace

Tags: c++, friend-function

```
/** module.h */
#pragma once

class A {
  friend void helpers::logValue(const A &);
  int _val;

public:
  A() {}
};

namespace helpers {
  static void logValue(const A &a) {
    std::cout << a._val;  // <== ERROR: '_val' is not accessible
  }
}
```

How do I declare the friend function in another namespace?

Comment: Is this the actual code you're compiling? I get a slew of different errors, starting with a missing semi-colon after `class A { }`. If I fix that then I get a series of errors that require forward declarations to fix. None of them are about `_val` being inaccessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way of solving this is as shown below:

```
class A;//forward declaration for class A
namespace helpers{
static void logValue(const A &a); //declaration
}
///////////////////////////////////////////

class A {
    
  friend void helpers::logValue(const A &);

  int _val;
};

namespace helpers {
  static void logValue(const A &a) {
    std::cout << a._val;  // works now
  }
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UvnSbP9hOd6xuABu).

Answer (score 5):

To come up with a solution, it is necessary to work backward.

We want this to work with `_val` a `private` member of class `A`.

```
namespace helpers {
    static void logValue(const A &a) {
       std::cout << a._val;
    }
}
```

**Step 1**  For the function definition above to work there must be a preceding definition of class `A` visible the compiler, and that class definition must specify that `helpers::logValue()` (with the appropriate signature i.e. return type and arguments) is a `friend`. So before the definition above of `helpers::logValue()` we must place;

```
class A {
    friend void helpers::logValue(const A &);

    int _val;
};
```

**Step 2** For that `friend` declaration in Step 1 to be valid, the compiler must know about `helpers::logValue()`.   That requires a declarative region of namespace `helpers` visible to the compiler that declares a function `logValue()` with the same signature, and that must be before the definition of `A`.   So, before our definition of class `A`, we must do something like;

```
namespace helpers{
   static void logValue(const A &a);
}
```

**Step 3**   The compiler will choke on this declaration of `helpers::logValue()` if there is no declaration of class `A` visible.     We already have a class definition (created in Step 1), so we cannot create another one (that would break the one-definition rule).   But we can add a declaration before the code from Step 2.

```
class A;
```

Putting those steps together, we put the code from the steps together in reverse order (i.e. put the code from Step 3 first, follow up with the code from Step 3, etc).  We then get

```
// Step 3
class A;

// Below Step 3 comes code from Step 2

namespace helpers{
   static void logValue(const A &a);    // works since A is declared
}

// Below Step 2 comes code from Step 1

class A {
    friend void helpers::logValue(const A &);   // works since helpers::logValue() is declared

    int _val;
};

//  And now we come to the function definition we want to have work

namespace helpers {
    static void logValue(const A &a) {
       std::cout << a._val;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for detailed explanation. My mistake was that I thought the expression `friend void helpers::logValue(const A &)` gave all the necessary information to the compiler .

Comment: It doesn't really give enough information.   In particular, on its own, `friend void helpers::logValue(const A &)` does not specify whether `helpers` is a namespace or a class (or a struct).   Also (if we - or the compiler - assume `helpers` is a class/struct) the declaration doesn't specify whether `logValue()` is a static or a non-static member.   To define `helpers::logValue()`, eventually, we have to tell the compiler what those things really are - and if the compiler has assumed something different, we're in trouble.  So we have to work back and declare everything in order, as described.